# Creating multiple asynctask for syncing files inside a service

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask, synchronization

I have created a service which i call from my main activity which syncs files to server. When service is called i call `new FileList().execute(); which provides the fileList for uploading and downloading. On postexecute of this asynctask i call two further asynctasks for uploading and downloading

```
for (int i = 0; i < files_server.size(); i++) {
            filename=files_server.get(i);
            new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(file_url+files_server.get(i));
            try {
                thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
 for (int j = 0; j < files_phone.size(); j++) {
            filePath=files_phone.get(j);
            new UploadFileToServer().execute();

            try {
                thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
```

the code for onStartcommand of service is

```
new FileList().execute();
    try {
        thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
    stopSelf();
    return mStartMode;
```

The code is working fine but as i am new on android, i couldn't find a way not to create so many asynctask together so i added delay which is not a proper solution. Help me with how to do this and whether service is a good option and whether stopping service like so is ok?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) instead of ASynchTask. I think you should create one IntentService implementing the task you need in the onHandleIntent method. At the end of the method you should send the obtained results to registered broadcast receivers through the sendBroadcast method.
Then, in a dedicated BroadcastReceiver you should implement and register you should catch the messages sent by your intent service and handle them.

After you have implemented such architecture you should start the intent service whenever you need from your activity/fragment.
By using intent services you don't have to deal with tasks queue and, yes, using delays to balance the queue is not a good idea in my humble opinion.